# How to rewrite URL GET parameters

Tags: .htaccess

I have a URL

`https://example.com/cart?prdid=223`
I want to redirect it to

```
https://example.com/cart/223
```

using .htaccess

i've tried to use

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)prdid=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^cart/(.*)$ /cart/$1?prdid=%1 [L,R]
```

But it does not work.

Comment: "I want to redirect it to" - Are you sure? Is that all you are trying to do? Does a URL of the form `/cart/223` already work on your site? If so, how is that implemented? What other directives do you have in the `.htaccess` file? The rule you posted would redirect a URL of the form `/cart/<foo>?prdid=<bar>` to `/cart/<foo>?prdid=<bar>` (ie. to itself - a redirect loop).

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite rules have the pattern to match first, *then* the result you want.

The pattern you need to match is the *current* URL, which just ends "/cart", with no extra slash or word on the end of it, so instead of `cart/(.*)$` you just want `cart$`

Then the *result* you want has the ID directly in the URL, not in the query string, and there's nothing for `$1` to refer to, only `%1` from the RewriteCond line. So instead of `/cart/$1?prdid=%1` you just want `/cart/%1`

Once you've fixed that, the browser will redirect to the new URL. To actually make that URL work, you'll probably need a *second* rule, without the `R` flag, to tell Apache what to do when it sees the "pretty" URL. That one *will* have `cart/(.*)$` as the pattern to match, but no condition on the query string, and `$1` in the result part, not `%1`